# Python, Django - how to store http requests in the middleware?

Tags: python, django, middleware

It might be that this question sounds pretty silly but I can not figure out how to do this I believe the simplest issue (because just start learning Django).

What I know is I should create a middleware file and connect it to the settings. Than create a view and a *.html page that will show these requests and write it to the urls.

- how can one store last (5/10/20 or any) http requests in the middleware and show them in a *.html page? The problem is I don't even know what exactly should I write into middlaware.py and views.py in the way it could be displayed in the *.html file. Ideally, this page should be also updated after the new requests occur. I read Django documentation, some other topics with middleware examples but it seems to be pretty sophisticated for me.

I would be really thankful for any insights and elucidates.

P.S. One more time sorry for a dummy question.

Comment: You can't store HTTP requests in the middleware itself. You'd need to save them to the db.

Comment: Thank you for answer, @DanielRoseman) However, I can not figure out the code which should be written for this purpose. Have already read a lot of blogs but still nothing.

Comment: Same way as you save anything else to the db. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, first of all, writing a proper code in the middleware.py. Like --- class SaveHttpRequests(object): def process_request(self, request): --- and what next? Or even this is completely wrong concept?

Comment: Looks like I have to create models for this purpose. But the proper code in the middleware.py is still under the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as you said, you need a model to save request information in database. After you have created and migrated your new model, you write your custom middleware and do what you want in `process_request` method:

```
from yourapp.models import YourModel

class CustomDebugMiddleware_first(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
         new_http_information = YourModel(http_info=INFO_YOU_WANT_TO_SAVE)
         new_http_information.save()
```

and then put the path to this middleware in your settings.py into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it really makes sense for me as for the absolute beginner)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `RequestMiddleware` (which plugs in before the URL resolution) or `ViewMiddleware` (which plugs in after the view has been resolved for the URL).

In that middleware, it's standard python. You have access to the filesystem, database, cache server, ... the same you have anywhere else in your code.

Showing the last *N* requests in a separate web page means you create a view which pulls the data from the place where your middleware is storing them.